# How to send smtp email without entering credentials (which often change)?

Tags: vb.net, email, smtp

I wrote the code below which works great. The code will be run on a schedule ( daily and/or weekly ) to process files and send an email at the end of processing with an attachment of results.
However this code requires network credentials (user and password).
However the password often changes. So how do i write the code to send the email without having to go in and change mmy code when the password changes?

```
  Dim SmtpServer As New SmtpClient()
  SmtpServer.EnableSsl = True
  Dim mail As New MailMessage()
  SmtpServer.Credentials = New Net.NetworkCredential("dw@my-org.org", "mypassword")
  SmtpServer.Port = 587
  SmtpServer.Host = "smtp.office365.com"
  mail = New MailMessage()
  mail.From = New MailAddress("dw@my-org.org")
  mail.To.Add("dw@my-org.org")
  mail.Subject = "Results of automatic Import of Time Card Punches to Attendance Application"
  mail.Body = "Attached are the CSV logs with the results of the automatic Import of Time Card Punches to Attendance Application. The import file contains logs of any new employee records createds or any changes to any existing employees. The import issues file will not contain any results unless there were errors during import."
  mail.Attachments.Add(New Attachment(LogFilename.ToString))
  mail.Attachments.Add(New Attachment(LogimportIssues.ToString))
  SmtpServer.Send(mail)
```

Comment: You'll have to put the username and password in a config file or a database.

Comment: But I would still have to constantly update it everytime the password changes, right?

Comment: Yes, especially if it's a office365 email. I think you'll have to ask yourself, what is the easiest way for me to change the email.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out that my server guy did something very smart.
If an email is going to internal users then I can use a SMTP server he set up and send it through without a password. Anything inside can send through that SMTP box. 
So i just changed the following 3 lines of code and it started working.
Changed from:

```
SmtpServer.Credentials = New Net.NetworkCredential("dw@my-org.org", "mypassword")
```

SmtpServer.Port = 587
  SmtpServer.Host = "smtp.office365.com"

to (not real host name below obviously):

```
SmtpServer.Credentials = New Net.NetworkCredential("dw@my-org.org", "")
```

SmtpServer.Port = 25
  SmtpServer.Host = "192.001.1.1"

I also removed the line below:

SmtpServer.EnableSsl = True

Now I can send SMTP emails internally without a password!

Answer (score 0):

A technique might be;
You can create a text file in a path and you can read from this text file (or whatever extension) the first line witch is your password
Every time you want to change password you need to update this file, from code you read always the password from this file.

```vb
   ' You need to update only your textfile
     Dim pwd As String = Trim(IO.File.ReadAllText("C:\WhateverFolder\YourFile.txt"))


    ' And in code doesn't need to change anything 
    SmtpServer.Credentials = New Net.NetworkCredential("dw@my-org.org", pwd)
```